# Laravel - ErrorException Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to refer all the possible solutions in stackoverflow but could not solve this.

This is my Controller.

```
public function getMessages(){
    $messages = Message::all()->toArray();
    return View('admin.thesis', ['messages' => $messages]);
}
```

This is  my route/web.php

```
Route::get ('/thesis','MessagesController@getMessages');
```

And this is my view

```
<div class="panel-heading">Thesis Details</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>E-Mail</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Article</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Uploaded File</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($messages as $row)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$row['firstName']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['lastName']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['email']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['contactNumber']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['state']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['country']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['article']}}</td>
                <td>{{$row['author']}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/uploads/{{$row['file_path']}}">
                      {{$row['file_path']}}
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my error

> ErrorException
>       Undefined variable: messages (View: 
>       *`C:\xampp\htdocs\fileupload\resources\views\admin\thesis.blade.php)`*

How do I resolve this?

Comment: code looks fine. can you print the messages value before you pass it to the view

Answer (score 3):

Try this on your *`Controller`*

```
public function getMessages(){
    $messages = Message::all();
    return view('admin.thesis')->with(['messages' => $messages]);
}
```

And in your blade file

```
@foreach($messages as $row)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $row->firstName }}</td>
    <td>{{ $row->lastName }}</td>
    <td>{{ $row->email }}</td>
    <!-- etc... -->
    <td>
       <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/uploads/{{ $row->file_path }}">
         {{ $row->file_path }}
       </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your *`Controller`*

```
public function getMessages(){
    $messages = Message::all()->toArray();
    return view('admin.thesis', compact('messages'));
}
```

Comment: Actually, his code is okay as his question & I don't have his code so I can't find the actual reason for this error. So I just provide my personal style that how I send data to view. I know this is not the perfect solution but maybe this can work or maybe not. Just try.

Comment: And you can not explain what the difference between the OP's code and yours is, and why that makes a difference to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I can't explain. Because both are the same. I just share my coding style to try.

Answer (score 0):

I used following code and its work for me :

```
class SidebarController extends Controller
{
    public function news_widget() {

        $posts = Post::take(5)->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->take();
        return view('index', array('data'=>$posts));
    }
}
```

And within the view I simply use `$data` and its working fine for me.